# Всегда надо добавлять addEventListener созданному скриптом объекту?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если элемент DOM создается динамически на странице и в нем должна быть кнопка/ссылка с функцией, всегда надо добавлять таким элементам addEventListener ?

[Пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPMeVE?editors=1111).

Строка с текстовым `input`, ниже кнопка "+ добавить строку", если добавить строку без `addEventListener` (сделал это в 6-й строке `$('.row:last a').on('click', removeRow);`) то строку невозможно удалить, так как `a.delete` не сработает, на ссылке нет функции `removeRow()`.

Всегда надо созданным элементам добавлять функции, которые они запускают? Задаю потому, что где-то мелькнула информация, что при применении "bind/live" вместо "on" этого делать не требуется.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#but').on('click', function(){
    var row = $('.row:last');
    row.clone().insertAfter(row);
    //addeventlistener
   $('.row:last a').on('click', removeRow);
  });
  
  $('.delete').on('click', removeRow);
  
  function removeRow(){
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <input type="text"> <a href="#" class="delete">x</a>
</div>
<input type="button" value="+" id="but">
```

Comment: Если удалить все строки, плюсик не добавит новую. Ловите баг)

Comment: @Denis вопрос сейчас не про это.

Comment: нет не обязательно, достаточно повесить обработчик на контейнер и делегировать событие по селектору, все это делается функцией `on` которая уже используется

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На вновь созданных элементов нет обработчиков, поэтому их надо добавлять вручную. Отличительная особенность функций `bind`, `live`, `delegate`, `on` в том, что они это делают за Вас и при их правильном использовании этого делать не надо. При этом обработчик `on` является более новым и объединяет в себе функциональность трех первых, которые в новых версиях JQuery желательно уже не использовать.

Используйте делегирующий способ задания обработчиков через `on` на контейнер верхнего уровня.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#but').on('click', function(){
    var row = $('.row:last');
    row.clone().insertAfter(row);
  });
  
  $('.rows').on('click', '.delete', removeRow);
  
  function removeRow(){
    $(this).closest('.row').remove();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text"> <a href="#" class="delete">x</a>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="+" id="but">
```

Comment: небольшое уточнение: `live` - _удален_ начиная с версии 1.9, остальные не помечены deprecated, но, `delegate` внутри себя вызывает `on` с теми же параметрами, а `bind` вызывает `on` но без параметра `selector`. Поэтому поведение может немного отличаться

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за уточнения, немного поправил ответ, что бы не вводить людей в заблуждения.

Comment: @AlexKrass так ведь `.row` тоже вновь созданный элемент, как так получается, что ему/потомку делегирован обработчик? Или это просто особенность трехпараметрового `on`?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, обработчик висит на внешнем `.rows` и на самом деле он обрабатывает событие `click`(+ оптимизация, создается только один обработчик). Как только вы нажали на любой элемент внутри `.rows`, событие всплывает и перехватывается им. При этом в JS есть возможность определить на какой элемент внутри вы нажали, как раз второй параметр '.delete' задает ограничение, для каких элементов выполнится функция removeRow, остальные будут проигнорированы. То есть обработчик делегируется(передается) верхнему контейнеру, который все разруливает.

Comment: @AlexKrass да, спасибо, я не заметил `rows` и `row`.