# Не работают функции jquery на контенте внутри блока, который грузится pjax'ом

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, yii2, pjax

Работаю на Yii2, использую для загрузки контентной части (одного блока - id="w0") pjax, в Asset подключен jquery скрипт, который работает с кнопкой внутри w0, в этом скрипте есть обработчик для кнопки:

```
$("#mybtn").click(function(){ console.log("its work!"); });
```

Если страницу обновить, то всё норм - кнопка работает. Если же на страницу перейти с другой, т.е. блок w0 загрузится через pjax, то обработчик на кнопку не вешается, я понимаю почему, но не знаю как решить эту проблему. Проблема не только с этой функцией, но и со всеми другими, на пример с стандартными функциями jquery-ui

Comment: потому что надо добавить кнопке addeventlistener или on() жкуревский. Но лучше всего использовать on() с [делегированием](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493707/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-addeventlistener-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83).

Comment: Без разницы какие функции, on() тоже не работает. Проблема в том, что обработчики привязываются после загрузки html, а тут он перезагружается через pjax и jquery просто не знает о том, что в новой разметке содержится, соответственно никакие обработчики не привязываются ни к кнопкам, ни к каким либо другим элементам.

Comment: воспроизведи проблему на кодепене/джсбин.

Answer (score 2):

Еще раз повторяю за делегирование, делегируйте на тот объект, который не грузится аджаксом. Пример:

Файл d.html  содержит

```
<input type="button" value="моя кнопка" id="mybtn">
```

Файл index.html, загрузка аджаксом контента происходит в div#res:

```
<body>
    <a href="#">Загрузить</a>
    <div id="res"></div>    
</body>
```

Если повесить обработчик так, то **не работает**

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $('#res').load('d.html');
});
$('#mybtn').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({'backgroundColor': 'lightgreen', 'border': '1px solid green'});
});
```

А так работает если делегировать на более высший в иерархии элемент, **то работает**:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $('#res').load('d.html');
});
$('body').on('click', '#mybtn', function() {
    $(this).css({'backgroundColor': 'lightgreen', 'border': '1px solid green'});
});
```

Comment: Хорошо, но покажите пример не с стандартными функциями (click, hover и т.д.) а на пример с функциями jquery-ui или любыми самописными.

Comment: пример самописной функции плиз

Comment: Да не обязательно с самописными, на пример функция из jquery-ui - sortable