# Удаление строк из таблицы созданной при помощи jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день! Вопрос следующий: у меня есть таблица для отправления данных, есть форма. В форме находятся 3, созданные мной при помощи html, строки.
Каждая строка состоит из 3х столбцов и кнопки удалить. При помощи Jquery реализовал добавление данных из формы в таблицу, а так же удаление строк, но удалять получается только те строки, которые были созданы ранее.
Как я удаляю строки:

```
$('.btn-primary').click(function()
{
    var ParentID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    delete(Tables[ParentID]);
    Tables.length--;
});
```

При нажатии на кнопку у строки, которую я создал при помощи jquery ничего не происходит.
Добавление строки в таблицу:

```
$('#SandButton').click(function ()
{
    var MProductName = $('#ProductName').val();
    var MPrice = $('#Price').val();
    var MNumber = $('#Number').val();

    MyMyProducts = new MyProduct(MProductName, MPrice, MNumber, i);
    Tables.push(MyMyProducts);
    $('#MyTable').append('<tr id =' +i+ '><td>' + MProductName + '</td><td>' + MPrice + '</td><td>' + MNumber +'</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="DeleteButton' + i + '">удалить</button></td></th>');
    console.log(Tables[i]);
    i++;
});
```

Сам вопрос, как удалять строки, которые я добавил в таблицу при помощи jquery?

upd
Попробовал переделать так, делегировать click

```
$(function () {
    $('#SandButton').on('click', function ()
    {
        var MProductName = $('#ProductName').val();
        var MPrice = $('#Price').val();
        var MNumber = $('#Number').val();

        MyMyProducts = new MyProduct(MProductName, MPrice, MNumber, i);
        Tables.push(MyMyProducts);
        $('#MyTable').append('<tr id =' + i + '><td>' + MProductName + '</td><td>' +
                MPrice + '</td><td>' + MNumber + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-primary"type="button" id="DeleteButton' + i + '">удалить</button></td></th>');
        i++;
    });
    $('#MyTable').on('click', '.btn-primary', DeleteRow());

    function DeleteRow() {
        $('.btn-primary').click(function ()
        {
            var ParentID = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            delete(Tables[ParentID]);
            Tables.length--;
        });
    }
});
```

Но результат все такой же, возможно, что что-то сделал не правильно, но что не могу понять...
UPD2 теперь по дабл-клику удаляет, но просто на клик никакой реакции.
UPD3 Теперь все работает!!! Всем спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: Вместо `click()` биндите `on("click", function() { ... })`

Comment: Что-то я не понял, просто сделать :    $('.btn-primary').on("click", function () { мой код}); так что ли? Это не работает.

Comment: хтмл код сюда предоставьте.

Comment: $('#MyTable').on('click', '.btn-primary', DeleteRow()); - DeleteRow() надо писать без скобок иначе эта функция сразу же выполняется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Про добавлении новых рядков таблицы динамически вы не добавляете им события `click`, а это необходимо делать. Но проще по-другому.

Поэтому используйте делегирующий способ задания обработчиков через `on` на контейнер верхнего уровня.

Тут `.rows` - контейнер верхнего уровня, можно вашу таблицу, `.delete` - динамически созданная вами в строке таблицы кнопка, `removeRow` - пользовательская функция или анонимная function(){}.

```
$('.rows').on('click', '.delete', removeRow);
```

Пример тут [Всегда надо добавлять addEventListener созданному скриптом объекту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493707/%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-addeventlistener-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83)

```js
  $(function() {
    //добавить строку табюлицы
    $('#but').on('click', function() {
      var row = $('.row:last');
      row.clone().insertAfter(row);
    });

    //удалить строку таблицы
    $('#tab').on('click', '.delete', removeRow);

    function removeRow() {
      $(this).closest('.row').remove();
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tab">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="имя">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="фамилия">
    </td>
    <td><a href="#" class="delete">x</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="добавить строку" id="but">
```

Comment: Таким образом мне нужно добавлять строки к таблице, так ведь?

Comment: Вообще не могу понять как в итоге должен выглядеть код добавления/удаления строк...

Comment: @ecofreeon дополнил ответ. Добавляете строки как обычно, удалять с привязкой на таблицу, а не саму строку.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста на обновление поста, сделал как в примере, но работает все точно так же