# Как подключить или как использовать javascript к элементам, которые загружаются с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

Сделал бесконечный скроллинг для комментариев, к каждому комментарию применяются различные js функции. Первые комментарии, которые загружаются на страницу работают отлично, но последующие, которые загружается с помощью файла `ajax.php` (условно) на js не реагируют вообще. Комментарии отображаются на странице `topic.php` в футоре которой подключены все мои js файлы, подключение этих же фалов к `ajax.php` (к файлу откуда загружаются дополнительные комментарии при скроллинге) приводит к огромному количеству ошибок, так как, получается, что мы подключаем js файлы дважды. Я уже второй день голову ломаю, казалось бы простая задача, но видимо не для новичка. Спасибо всем, кто откликнется!

```
//Infinite scroll
flag = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()){
    first = $('#first').val();
    limit = $('#limit').val();
idt = $('#idt').val();
    no_data = true;
    if(flag && no_data){
        flag = false;
        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
            data: {
               start : first,
               limit : limit,
       idt : idt
            },
            success: function( data ) {
                flag = true;
                $('#loader').hide();
                if(data !=''){

                    first = parseInt($('#first').val());
                    limit = parseInt($('#limit').val());
                    $('#first').val( first+limit );
                        $('#timeline-container').append( data );

                        $('.timeline-item, .timeline-inverted').waypoint({
                            triggerOnce: true,
                            offset: '80%',
                            handler: function() {
                                jQuery(this).addClass('animated fadeInUp');
                            }
                        });
                }else{
                    alert('No more data to show');
                    no_data = true;
                }
            },
            error: function( data ){
                flag = true;
                $('#loader').hide();
                no_data = false;
                alert('Something went wrong, Please contact admin');
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: "к каждому комментарию применяются различные js функции." - добавьте в вопрос хотя бы один пример. Также - типичную разметку для комментария.

Answer (score 1):

Все очень легко и просто, навешиваете на сам документ события для разных классов, и если элемент с таким классом появиться на странице он его подхватит и будет с ним работать.

И да не нужно этот код пихать в DomReady!

```
$(document).on(eventName, '.myClassName', function(){
// тут код функции
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.myClassName', function(){
    alert('Ой нажали!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class='myClassName'>Ткни по мне</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ, к сожалению, не до конца понимаю как это можно применить к моей проблеме. То есть, например при загрузке страницы topic.php (где все комментарии отображаются) выполнить функцию append для div-a  с комментариями, которые загрузились из ajax.php? Но это не работает

Comment: Вам нужно переписать файл в котором содержаться JS функции для комментариев, чтобы комменты которые будут добавляться при помощи AJAX так же могли работать.

Comment: Сделал именно так, но не работает, потому что нет никакой реакции на div с новыми комментами... В общем, я еще буду голову дальше ломать, Ваш ответ пока меня только навел

Comment: Лучше дайте код в вопросе, так точно быстрее вам помогут. Не понимаю логики построения вопроса, это вы видите свой код остальные его не видят.... потому и ответа вам адекватного ни кто не даст.

Comment: Добавил js код вызова ajax.php, проверьте пожалуйста

Comment: @JohnnyCatsville это называется делегирование, вот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493707/%d0%92%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-addeventlistener-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83